# Laravel 8 Image Crop Upload dimension restrictions

Tags: laravel, image, crop, cropper

I have seen a lot of tutorials on cropping images before uploading them in Laravel. My issues is that I do not want the users to decide the dimensions of the image before they upload. I want to set the default dimensions so that all the user does is drag around which areas of the image they want to crop with the dimensions I have set for them.
Any JS package that allows me to do this easily? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you earlier, and solved it using a javascript package named [CropperJs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/).

Cropper allows you to set a fixed image-ratio that the user can not change. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730887/how-to-get-a-fixed-sized-crop-from-cropper) on how to implement the fixed ratio using [CropperJs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) :)

Good luck!

Comment: @wmiriye.miriye If the answer solved your issue, please mark the it as an answer to, that would make more people find the solution to this problem.